# Невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из bool в jboolean - JNI C++

Tags: c++, jni, преобразование-типов

Компилятор сообщил, что в этой части кода ошибка
`Ошибка C2664   "const char *JNIEnv_::GetStringUTFChars(jstring,jboolean *)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 2 из "bool" в "jboolean *"`

```
std::string name( ) {
        jmethodID get_name = minecraft->m_jenv->GetMethodID( minecraft->m_jenv->GetObjectClass( java_class ), "e_", "()Ljava/lang/String;" );
        jstring name = ( jstring ) minecraft->m_jenv->CallObjectMethod( java_class, get_name );
        return std::string( minecraft->m_jenv->GetStringUTFChars( name, false ) );
    }
```

[image: Скриншот]

Абсолютно не могу понять, в чем проблема. Использую JNI C++, версия jdk - 1.8
[image: Настройки]

Comment: Второй аргумент указатель на jboolean, а передается значение.

Comment: @nevilad, сделай это как ответ, пожалуйста. Мало ли кому то будет нужно, а вопрос будет удален

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй аргумент указатель на `jboolean`:

```
const char *JNIEnv_::GetStringUTFChars(jstring,jboolean *)
```

В примере же передается значение (`false`):

```
return std::string( minecraft->m_jenv->GetStringUTFChars( name, false ) );
```

Надо передавать указатель:

```
jboolean bVar = false;
return std::string( minecraft->m_jenv->GetStringUTFChars( name, &bVar ) );
```

Comment: Дополнение - Можно использовать JNI_FALSE вместо создания еще одной переменной и указании ссылки

Comment: `JNI_FALSE` определен как `#define JNI_FALSE 0`, т.е. так передастся нулевой указатель.